# Pandas - Duplicate rows based on a condition and simultaneously change a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample pandas dataframe (df) that looks like:

```
Thomas McMann   30     0      0          1172
 Johnny Chien   25     0      1          1172
 Robert McDoe   68     1      0          1172
  Jason Singh  104     1      0          1172
Sarah Jessica   13     0      0          1172
```

My goal is to duplicate the columns where 'Flag' or 'Flag2' are equal to '1', and then change the assigned_code in the duplicated column as per follows:

if 'Flag' = 1, 'assigned_code' = 1105
if 'Flag2' = 1, 'assigned_code' = 1050

The resulting output would look as follows:

```
          Name  Age  Flag  Flag2 assigned_code
Thomas McMann   30     0      0          1172
 Johnny Chien   25     0      1          1172
 Johnny Chien   25     0      1          1050
 Robert McDoe   68     1      0          1172
 Robert McDoe   68     1      0          1105
  Jason Singh  104     1      0          1172
  Jason Singh  104     1      0          1105
Sarah Jessica   13     0      0          1172
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am new to python and have been looking through a bunch of previously answered questions but I can't seem to find a solution that would work for my dataset.

Comment: Is it possible both Flag and Flag2 would be 1?

Comment: For the data that I will be working with, that would not be possible, thank you for checking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) + [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to scale up the DataFrame then [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). Then we can use [`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html#pandas.DataFrame.dot) to modify the `assigned_code` based on where index was [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and the Flags:

```
idx = df.index.repeat((df['Flag'] | df['Flag2']) + 1)
df = df.loc[idx].reset_index(drop=True)

m = idx.duplicated()
df.loc[m, 'assigned_code'] = df.loc[m, ['Flag', 'Flag2']].dot([1105, 1050])
```

`df`:

```
            Name  Age  Flag  Flag2  assigned_code
0  Thomas McMann   30     0      0           1172
1   Johnny Chien   25     0      1           1172
2   Johnny Chien   25     0      1           1050
3   Robert McDoe   68     1      0           1172
4   Robert McDoe   68     1      0           1105
5    Jason Singh  104     1      0           1172
6    Jason Singh  104     1      0           1105
7  Sarah Jessica   13     0      0           1172
```

---

Explanation:

DataFrame and imports.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Thomas McMann', 'Johnny Chien', 'Robert McDoe', 'Jason Singh',
             'Sarah Jessica'],
    'Age': [30, 25, 68, 104, 13],
    'Flag': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    'Flag2': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    'assigned_code': [1172, 1172, 1172, 1172, 1172]
})
```

We determine which rows are repeated by logical OR Flag and Flag2:

```
df['Flag'] | df['Flag2']

0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
dtype: int64
```

Then we add 1 to make 0 repeated 1 time and 1 repeated 2 times:

```
(df['Flag'] | df['Flag2']) + 1

0    1
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    1
dtype: int64
```

We then select repeat the index and select from the DataFrame with `loc`:

```
df.index.repeat((df['Flag'] | df['Flag2']) + 1)
Int64Index([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], dtype='int64')

df.loc[df.index.repeat((df['Flag'] | df['Flag2']) + 1)]

            Name  Age  Flag  Flag2  assigned_code
0  Thomas McMann   30     0      0           1172
1   Johnny Chien   25     0      1           1172
1   Johnny Chien   25     0      1           1172
2   Robert McDoe   68     1      0           1172
2   Robert McDoe   68     1      0           1172
3    Jason Singh  104     1      0           1172
3    Jason Singh  104     1      0           1172
4  Sarah Jessica   13     0      0           1172
```

`reset_index` is used to make the index unique again.

---

Value Replacement:

`index.duplicated` will indicate where there are new duplicated rows:

```
m = idx.duplicated()
[False False  True False  True False  True False]
```

This allows just selecting the new rows:

```
df.loc[m, ['Flag', 'Flag2']]

   Flag  Flag2
2     0      1
4     1      0
6     1      0
```

The `dot` product works to get the correct mapping assuming Flag and Flag2 will always be 1 or the other:

```
df.loc[m, ['Flag', 'Flag2']].dot([1105, 1050])

2    1050
4    1105
6    1105
dtype: int64
```

Alternatively we could use 2 `loc` assignments:

```
df.loc[m & df['Flag'].eq(1), 'assigned_code'] = 1105
df.loc[m & df['Flag2'].eq(1), 'assigned_code'] = 1050
```

Comment: Upvoted.   How about if BOTH flags are `1` ?   Should the repeat value be 2 or 3 ?

Comment: That's a great question @SeaBean I assumed "repeated if either" meant OR, but we could just as easily use +. I put that question up in the question.

Comment: Yes, it depends on whether the `or` is `XOR` (exclusive or) or not.  Sometimes laymen terms for it is not exclusive.  So, have to sum each.